# Visual Studio not recognizing emulator (AVD)

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, android-emulator

I'm developing a Cordova app in Visual Studio. I created 3 emulators in the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager, and they run fine, with HAXM. I'd like to debug my app using it, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize it - it just shows 'Install Android Emulators'.

Clicking on 'Install Android Emulators' just brings up a dialog that says that something is missing. Hyper-V is not installed.

[image: Visual Studio debug devices]

[image: AVD Manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was using Visual Studio 2017 - switching back to 2015 fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Virtualization for your PC, see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/)

Comment: That's only for the Visual Studio emulator - Google Emulator's don't use Hyper-V. See https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-apache/ for the 2 types.

Comment: same issue i did got when trying to build using visual studio 2015, enable Virtualization fix issue for me, also make sure sdk and build tool installed there properly.

Comment: windows home doesn't have hyper-v

Comment: I got Windows Pro and installed hyper-v, but it didn't help.